# C++ need assistance with if != to a random number

Tags: c++, if-statement, random

I am working on a project and I am stuck. I have two variables that generate random numbers. I want to do a check that checks to make sure the variables are not the same number, and if they are, then repeat the process until they are not the same. Here is what I have :

```
num_enemy = 3;

int f =  rand() % num_enemy;
int m =  rand() % num_enemy;

if ( f != m )
{
enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
}
```

The code above wont work plus how can I make it so that if its false it will generate the random numbers again?

I am not looking for answers, just assistance on what exactly I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a loop.

Comment: While loops are too much of an accepted answer, use recursive function just because you can :D

Comment: c'mon, he wants do to it at least once - finally a time for my beloved `do{}while();` loop! *wheeeee*

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when it gets to this section...

```
if ( f != m )
{
    enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
    enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
}
```

... the variables `f` and `m` could have the same value, due to the modulo, so your `fire_Weapon()` and `update_Status()` functions are never called. You will need to loop until both variables have different values. The code below should sort you out.

```
const int num_enemy = 3;
int f = rand() % num_enemy;
int m;

// A do-while loop is guaranteed to be called at least once.
do
{
    m = rand() % num_enemy;
} while ( f == m ); // Repeat the loop if the values are the same

// At this point, f and m will always have different values.
enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
```

Because your variables are modulo with a low value, it's possible the loop may have to run many times before `f != m`.

Also, if you want the sequence of pseudo-random numbers returned by `rand()` to be different each time the game is run, seed the psuedo-random number generator with a call to `srand( time() )` once. If you want the sequence to be constant each time you run the game leave it as is. This can greatly help with debugging, and is required if your game needs to be [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system).

Read more about `rand()` and `srand()` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

As mentioned in another answer, C++11 has improved random number generation. Find out more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to @vdua's answer, but much cleaner in my opinion. Always remember to call `srand` before this code is encountered though, or else you'll hit an infinite loop.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, Not correct. srand() is not required for rand() to function correctly.

Answer (score 4):

one solution is

```
num_enemy = 3;

int f =  rand() % num_enemy;
int m =  rand() % num_enemy;
while(f==m) {
    f = rand() % num_enemy;
    //m = rand() % num_enemy;
}
enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
```

But you should read [Reservoir sampling](http://gregable.com/2007/10/reservoir-sampling.html) to learn how to select k numbers randomly from a set. you can have an array of integers from 1 to num_enemy. Then select two numbers randomly from this array. It's an order n solution and if your array is small, it would work great.

EDIT: based on the comment edited the code

Comment: You don't need to replace *both* random numbers in the loop - replacing one of them is enough.

Answer (score 4):

"The code above won't work" is a little vague. I guess you mean that `f == m` every time?

In that case you may have forgotten to *seed* the RNG. See the documentation for [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/). Or better yet, use the new c++ [Random Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) for pseudo-random number generators.

As for how to regenerate the random numbers when `f == m`... are you aware of `while` loops? It would be a good idea to read up on [control structures](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#loops) and simple c++ syntax.

Comment: A call to srand() is not required for rand() to function correctly.

Comment: @DrTwox How do you figure?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/ "Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX. This number is generated by an algorithm that returns a sequence of apparently non-related numbers each time it is called." Go try it and see :)

Comment: If you want `rand` to generate seemingly-random numbers through every run and you *don't* call `srand`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Correct, but you don't HAVE to call srand() before rand() for it to work, and sometimes you do want the sequence to be random within each run, but the same (predictable) for every run.

Comment: Why not just [choose constant values](http://xkcd.com/221/) then? At least that would be portable. I believe that the use of `rand` without one preceding `srand` is an error. And the use of `rand/srand` in new c++ code is also an error.

Comment: My issue is with this part of your answer: "I guess you mean that f == m every time? In that case you may have forgotten to seed the RNG." This is wrong and not how rand() and srand() work.

Comment: Not necessarily in this case. There was no loop, just two calls to `rand`. It's reasonable to suggest that in this instance the OP got `m == f` every time the program ran.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, you can ensure that the second random number will be different than the first by picking from a pool of one less possibility:

```
num_enemy = 3;

int f =  rand() % num_enemy;

// pick another non-zero number from a pool that's smaller by one than before
int next_offset =  1 + (rand() % (num_enemy-1));

// add it to the previous result (modulo the range)
int m = (f + next_offset) % num_enemy;

assert( 0 <= f && f < num_enemy);
assert( 0 <= m && m < num_enemy);
assert( f != m );

enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
```

Of course, because `rand()` isn't necessarily a great RNG and because simply using `%` to map the random number to a certain range usually introduces a bias, you might want to tweak the implementation of this to deal with those problems if that's important.

And if you prefer the looping solution, there's no need to keep picking both numbers (though I imagine there's not much harm, either):

```
int f =  rand() % num_enemy;
int m;

do {
    m = rand() % num_enemy;
} while (f == m);
```

Comment: +1 I also prefer the "one less" approach.  For a simpler implementation: `int m = rand() % (num_enemy - 1); if (m == f) m = num_enemy - 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to repeat something on some condition, what you need is a loop, the construction made for repetition. In this case, since you want to do the thing at least once before checking the condition, I would suggest a do-while loop:

```
 int f, m;
 do {
   f = rand() % num_enemy;
   m = rand() % num_enemy;
 } while(f == m);

 enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
 enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
```

Comment: DrTwox said almost the same slightly earlier but this would actually work (you have assignments in the loop, not new variable declarations) so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_enemy = 3;

int f =  rand() % num_enemy;
int m =  rand() % (num_enemy-1);
m += (m>=f);

enemy_ptr[f] -> fire_Weapon();
enemy_ptr[m] -> update_Status();
```

The idea is that whatever number `f` gets is taken out of the set of possible values for `m`. Since a value has been removed from the possible set for `m`, we reduce the number of possible values for `m` by using `% (num_enemy-1)`, and adjust whatever value is picked for `m` to be one of the possible values. That is, if `m` is greater than or equal to the value picked for `f`, we add one. This is 'cleverly' written as `m += (m>=f);` because the boolean value gets converted to zero or one.

Also, `rand()` is not usually a good random number generator, and using mod does not do a good job of producing a uniform distribution in your desired range. You should use the C++11 `<random>` library.

```
#include <random>

int num_enemy = 3;

// set up decent random number engine and distributions
std::mt19937 eng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> f_dist{0, num_enemy-1};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> m_dist{0, num_enemy-2};

int f = f_dist(eng);
int m = m_dist(eng);
m += (m>=f);
```